# media queries for 13 inch monitor

Tags: html, css, media-queries

my layout works fine in big monitors....
but i am trying to display properly in small screen laptops....
which width should i need to use it in the css media queries for the 13 inch monitor...
i am confused abt width for 13 inch laptop

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
@media (max-width: 767px) {
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
@media (max-width: 767px) {
@media (max-width: 480px) {
@media (max-width: 979px) {
@media (min-width: 980px) {
```

Comment: Size doesn't matter, resolution does. What resolution does the 13 inch laptop have?

Comment: Well *my* 13-inch laptop has a resolution of 1280x800.

Comment: Don't use media queries to target devices, use media queries to target the spots where your content breaks instead.

Comment: In this scenario I covered 768, 1400, and everything bigger as my css. I used it pretty minimal, but somehow using VH for my padding/margins broke on 13inch laptops.

Answer (score 4):

Most 13" monitors are going to be larger than **960px** or even larger than **1140px** wide.  **960px** wide is kind of an old standard, more often now **1140px** is used, especially for responsive design.

That said, only a netbook with a 8" or 9" screen will have issues displaying.  Every 13" monitor I know of should not have any issues displaying your web page.  If you want to design for the netbook, they are similar in resolution to most tablets in portrait position.  So if you are doing media queries for tablet and mobile phone, then the netbooks should adopt the styles of the tablet, as their resolutions are **800x600** up to **1024x768**.

In general, there is no reason to make a different set of styles for anything other than mobile phone and tablet.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can fund all resolutions and their screen sizes:

http://www.codeply.com/responsive-design-cheatsheet.html

**For the question you asked:
13' Macbook Air    1440 px x 900px     13 inches**

For more testings and research, You can also check this website that tests all required screen resolutions as well provide option to enter custom screen sizes:

http://www.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php

PS: None of the websites I mentioned above are connected to me, I am just a regular user and a web developer.